# How to get the ID of a selected item in a combobox in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, dropdown

I am able to populate the value to the dropdown as under

### app.js

```
export class App {

  constructor() {

    this.countryCollection = [
  {
    "CountryID": "1",
    "CountryName": "Japan"
  },
  {
    "CountryID": "2",
    "CountryName": "USA"
  },
  {
    "CountryID": "3",
    "CountryName": "Canada"
  },
  {
    "CountryID": "4",
    "CountryName": "Sweden"
  }
];

  }  
}
```

### app.html

```
<template>
<h2>
  <select>
        <option value="">-Choose Country-</option>
        <option value="${country.CountryID}"                
                repeat.for="country of countryCollection">${country.CountryName}</option>
    </select>
</template>
```

But to get the selected Country ID on Change event of the drop down ?

Comment: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-selects/3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add a `selectedCountryId` to the `app.js` and then change the select to

```
<select value.bind="selectedCountryId">
        <option model.bind="null">-Choose Country-</option>
        <option model.bind="country.CountryID"                
                repeat.for="country of countryCollection">${country.CountryName}</option>
    </select>
```

which will bind the country id that has been selected to the selectedCountryId property of your `.js` file. This is pulled straight from their documentation [here](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-selects/2).